# Recursive GCD using a lambda

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda

This works just fine, however, the assignment was to write a recursive "function".  I'm curious to see if this should count.

Any comments / suggestions/ stuff I should watch out for are appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {

    char go_again = 'Y';

    do {

        int lhs, rhs;
        std::cout << "Enter 2 integer values: ";
        std::cin >> lhs >> rhs;

        if (lhs < 0 || rhs < 0)
            std::cout << "Implicit converstion to positive integers.\n";

        std::function<int(int, int)> 
            gcd = [&](int lhs, int rhs) -> int { 
                return rhs == 0 ? std::abs(lhs) : gcd(rhs, lhs % rhs); 
        };

        std::cout << "gcd == " << gcd(lhs, rhs) << '\n';
        std::cout << "Go again? <Y/N> ";
        std::cin >> go_again;

    } while (std::toupper(go_again) == 'Y');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that familiar with C++, but that certainly looks like recursion to me...

The variable gcd contains a function, which then calls itself.  The very definition of recursion.

But I would ask what you gain by not making it a regular function?